# What are export_includes and import_includes files when building Android

Tags: android, makefile

Can't find any useful info on this using Google.

All I found are people asking how to resolve compilation errors such as

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/joe/[ubuntuTouch]/out/target/product/jewel/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libril_intermediates/export_includes', needed by `/home/joe/[ubuntuTouch]/out/target/product/jewel/obj/EXECUTABLES/rild_intermediates/import_includes'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Please look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23107212/2083078)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone does come here with that compilation error, I had this problem when I switched to a different terminal window and forgot to call `lunch`. (I had called `source build/envsetup.sh`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I looked closely at the error stack, it seemed that the */hardware/ril* folder of the AOSP had gotten corrupted.

My solution was to remove the entire folder *(/hardware)* and then redo **repo sync**. This fixed the sources and it took about 3 minutes. But I do think that it will work best if your development environment is setup according to [AOSP source download](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you have to **sync ril-caf repo from cm or lineage os** .It was missing in your source.